# How do you use realloc when you have a pointer to a pointer of a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I have this array of structs and this function takes a pointer to the pointer of the array.  The original size is 2, so whenever it reaches the size, I need to realloc and double the size.  When this code runs, I get an invalid old size error from the realloc.  What am I doing wrong?

```
  int PopulateArray(struct Inventory **inv, int *size, FILE *inputFile) {
    int count = 0;
    printf("address: %u\n", inv);
    printf("address: %u\n", **inv);
    int itemNumber;
    int quantity;
    float price;
    int month;
    int year;
    while (fscanf(inputFile, "%i %i %f %i/%i", &itemNumber,
    &quantity, &price, &month, &year) != EOF) {
      (*inv)->itemNumber = itemNumber;
      (*inv)->quantity = quantity;
      (*inv)->price = price;
      (*inv)->expDate.month = month;
      (*inv)->expDate.year = year;
      printf("count: %i  size: %i\n", count, *size);

      if (count == *size - 1) {
        inv = realloc(inv, (*size * 2 * sizeof(struct Inventory)));
        *size *= 2;
      }
      inv++;
      count++;
    }
    return count;
  }
```

Comment: `while(fscanf(...) != EOF)` is not safe. Consider what happens when *some* but not *all*  of the conversions succeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function, `inv` is (presumably) the address of a pointer variable.  Its the value of that variable you want to pass to `realloc`.

```
*inv = realloc(*inv, (*size * 2 * sizeof(struct Inventory)));
```

For the same reason, incrementing `inv` itself won't do what you expect.

Because you need to use `realloc`, you should use `count` to reference the array.

```
while (fscanf(inputFile, "%i %i %f %i/%i", &itemNumber,
    &quantity, &price, &month, &year) != EOF) {
  (*inv)[count].itemNumber = itemNumber;
  (*inv)[count].quantity = quantity;
  (*inv)[count].price = price;
  (*inv)[count].expDate.month = month;
  (*inv)[count].expDate.year = year;
  printf("count: %i  size: %i\n", count, *size);

  if (count == *size - 1) {
    *inv = realloc(*inv, (*size * 2 * sizeof(struct Inventory)));
    if (*inv == NULL) {
        perror("realloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    *size *= 2;
  }
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem occurs because you're modifying `inv` (`inv++;`).

You can only `realloc` data if the passed pointer is a valid allocated pointer, not a pointer *within* the allocated zone.

So you have to store your `inv` data so you can use `realloc`. Pointer on the current element must be a different variable.

And check that `realloc` doesn't return `NULL` before assigning back to `inv` or you'll lose your original pointer.

That almost made me miss the biggest mistake (1 mistake hiding the other, classical): you're passing a `struct Inventory **` type so you can modify the pointer, but you're modifying the double pointer instead.

You should perform your realloc on the pointed value, not on the address of the pointer:

```
*inv = realloc(*inv, (*size * 2 * sizeof(struct Inventory)));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you update `inv` from `realloc()`, your `inv` now points to the *start* of the newly resized array. So, your code

```
  if (count == *size - 1) {
    inv = realloc(inv, (*size * 2 * sizeof(struct Inventory*)));
    *size *= 2;
  }
  inv++;
```

the last `inv++` will make `inv` point effectively to `inv[1]`, not the `inv[count]` which you would probably wanted to point to.

*I am adding below because incorrect answers are being upvoted*

The suggestion of

```
*inv = realloc(*inv, (*size * 2 * sizeof(struct Inventory)));
```

is not correct.

What you are attempting to do is doubling the array of pointers dynamically. So the correct pointer type to pass to `realloc` here is `struct Inventory **`.

(You probably created initial table by `pptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Inventory*) * INIT_SIZE)`, so `inv` is correct type for `realloc` here)

Having said that, after you performing the `realloc` in your function, the original `inv` pointer used by the code that called *this* function is no longer valid, so upon returning this function, you lose your pointer to the resized array. To deal with this, you have to return the new `inv` pointer value to the calling function.

additional edit:

And don't forget to allocate memory for the actual `struct Inventory` item:

```
inv[count] = malloc(sizeof(struct Inventory));
```

at the start of the loop.